# How can I validate an email address in CakePHP 1.3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I wanted to integrate a verified email address functionality in CakePHP 1.3.

I have used valid email address regular expressions but I have never ever verified an email address' domain (a valid domain name means existing domain name).

I know how this is done in plain PHP but I want to use CakePHP's functionality to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already built-in functionality you can use.

Read the documentation:

- [Cake 2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3aemail)
- [Cake 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Validation.html#email)

Note the `boolean $deep = false` param which you can use to actually check for the domains existence.

Answer (score 1):

assign this into your model

```
public $validate = array(       
        'email' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => array('email',true),
                'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
);
```